# How do I smooth out rounded hard surfaces that have unwanted bumps?

Tags: vertices, topology, bump

When working on 3D models of aircraft, that typically are more or less cylindrical, I often accidentally end up with ugly looking bumps where one or several vertices apparently have ended up slightly in the wrong place, which shows up as that location being shaded clearly differently in the 3D view: [image] (This particular mesh is not completely my own work but based on a suitably licensed model from Sketchfab. But, infuriatingly, the bump seems to have been caused by my (as such, I think, necessary) editing...)

and here in edit mode: [image]

Any hints how to solve this? I have tried moving the vertex that seems to be the problem minimal amounts in or out, but it doesn't help. Should I just redo the problematic part of the mesh while it still is this "clean" (before I have started doing any texturing, adding various smaller bits and pieces that the aircraft has on its surface, etc? Start with a perfect cylinder and then very carefully use the scale function on the vertex loops to modify its shape as needed. Is the key to smoothness to never touch individual vertices "manually"?

Or should I even, gasp, go full programmaing nerd and use code (geometry nodes) to generate the mesh?

Edit: Here is how it should look. Sadly I can't just go back to this as I have done many essential edits elsewhere in the model.[image]

Comment: I'm sure you could build the same object with a better topology but maybe use a second object underneath and try a shrinkwrap? Or try a right clock > LoopTools > Relax?

Comment: I wonder if I using NURBS would be a good idea? Divide the fuselage in sections with one NURBS cylinder used for each. (As Blender is not the end consumer of this work, I would keep the original NURBS objects "hidden" and duplicate and convert them to meshes before exporting, of course.)

Comment: do you have a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I added a picture of the same part in the original model.

Comment: ok but you don't show the whole object, it just looks like a cylinder, does it need more vertices on the left? could you use less vertices (for example can you use Subdivision Surface modifier?)? Also maybe you could share the object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I fixed this by removing the vertex in question and the four edges around it, and re-added them simply using the <kbd>J</kbd> *Vertex Connect Path*. That turned out to look just fine, even if in theory that should have made the loop around the fuselage *less* smooth. Oh well.